# c# ASP.Net grouped count query

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a query that returns a group count as follows

```
        private void ListCount(SqlConnection objConnection, string dealerId)
    {
        string strQueryCount = "SELECT tblUsers.DealerId, tblUsers.StatusId, COUNT(tblUsers.StatusId) as statuscount FROM tblUsers where tblUsers.DealerId =  " + dealerId + " group by tblUsers.StatusId, tblUsers.DealerId";

        SqlCommand sqlStatusCount = new SqlCommand(strQueryCount, objConnection);

        SqlDataReader sqlDRStatusCount = sqlStatusCount.ExecuteReader();

    }
```

This returns 3 columns one with the dealerid one with the status number and one with the count

[image]

What I am trying to do is get the count to show on my ascx file depending on status id.

I.E. on my ascx file i have the various statuses at top of page colour coded for the list of users below and i am trying to put the count next to them

I have a temp variable setup in my ascx.cs file

```
TestCount1.Text = "1";
TestCount2.Text = "2";
TestCount3.Text = "3";
TestCount4.Text = "4";
TestCount6.Text = "6";
TestCount7.Text = "7";
TestCount8.Text = "8";
```

which I am calling in my ascx file using

```xaml
<asp:Literal ID="TestCount3" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Being totally new to C# and .Net I am hitting a barrier with this and any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear where exactly you have problems. Is it the sql part?

Comment: `i am trying to put the count next to them`  <- Then  append the returned values with'em?  like e.g: `TestCount3.Text = "3 :" + DbCountValue ;`

Comment: Do you try using loop through result? post the code that you use to retrieve result from database ?

Comment: Hi its the looping through results i cannot get my head around i have looked through various codes but cant figure out what to use or do

Comment: I understand what your saying ARr0w but what i can get is how i set my databasecount value for each of the statusid counts

Comment: please show how you run this query from your C# right now

Comment: this is the code i have at the moment for the query

private void ListCount(SqlConnection objConnection, string dealerId)

 {
string strQueryCount = "SELECT tblUsers.DealerId, tblUsers.StatusId, COUNT(tblUsers.StatusId) as statuscount FROM tblUsers where tblUsers.DealerId =  " + dealerId + " group by tblUsers.StatusId, tblUsers.DealerId";

SqlCommand sqlStatusCount = new SqlCommand(strQueryCount, objConnection);
}

Comment: please edit that into your question, in the comments it's barely readable. Thanks. At a brief glance though it seems you never actually execute your query?

Comment: I have updated code in question and i had missed the last line in my comment

Comment: Ok so you need to make a loop to read each row from the reader. Have you followed any kind of basic ADO.NET tutorial showing how you use a DataReader? It should have demonstrated the correct usage.

Comment: Ive had a look at a couple will carry on looking thanks